# How to find out the class/type of parameter inside a function in R

Tags: r, function, parameters

The Problem raised from this:　I want to use certain function many times with different parameter,
in this case: .data = parm1, .variable = parm2 , cumsum(parm3)

```
df2 <- ddply(.data = df2, .variables = c("cookie_id"),transform,
                 cumcnt = cumsum(contflag))

df2 <- ddply(.data = df2, .variables = c("cookie_id","sex"),transform,
                 cumcnt = cumsum(income))

df2 <- ddply(.data = df2, .variables = c("cookie_id","nation"),transform,
                 cumcnt = cumsum(family_num))
```

## Then I'm trying to simplify it:

```
lapply(parm_list, function(parm1,parm2,parm3) ddply(.data = parm1,
                                                    .variables = parm2,
                                                    transform,
                                                    cumcnt = cumsum(parm3)))
```

I think the problem is:
parm1 is an object which I know how to pass
parm2 is char which I know how to pass
parm3 .. I don't know what kind of class it is
so I don't know how to pass parm3 into this function

So, is there any method to accomplish what I want, or is there any method to find out the class of parm3?

Comment: Add a `browser()` statement right before `ddply` and once you run the `lapply` part, you will be inside your anonymous function. Happy exploring.